# Is my calculation of $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{x+y}{\sqrt{y^2-x^2}}$ correct?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Is my calculation of the partial derivative (with respect to $x$) of the function $$f(x,y)=\frac{x+y}{\sqrt{y^2-x^2}}$$ correct?

> $$f'_x=\frac{\sqrt{y^2-x^2}-(x+y)(\frac{-x}{\sqrt{y^2-x^2}})}{|y^2-x^2|}\\=\frac{\sqrt{y^2-x^2}+\frac{x^2+xy}{\sqrt{y^2-x^2}}}{|y^2-x^2|}\\=\frac{\frac{|y^2-x^2|+x^2+xy}{\sqrt{y^2-x^2}}}{|y^2-x^2|}\\=|y^2-x^2|\frac{|y^2-x^2|+x^2+xy}{\sqrt{y^2-x^2}}$$

Comment: Looks right to me.  A point about notation, though, is that I've only seen $f_x$ for the derivative with respect to $x$, not $f'_x$.

Comment: The absolute value is technically not needed, because y²-x² can't become negative due to domain

Comment: It appears that all but the last step are good, why isn't there a $(y^2-x^2)^{\tfrac 32}$ in the denominator?

Comment: @imranfat $$x>y$$?

Comment: @marcelolpjunior. Check the domain of the given function.  x>y is not allowed due to the radical and thus not in the function's domain

Comment: $$y^2-x^2>0\\y^2>x^2\\y>x$$

Answer (score 0):

All correct except the last line

> $$f'_x=\frac{\sqrt{y^2-x^2}-(x+y)(\frac{-x}{\sqrt{y^2-x^2}})}{|y^2-x^2|}\\=\frac{\sqrt{y^2-x^2}+\frac{x^2+xy}{\sqrt{y^2-x^2}}}{|y^2-x^2|}\\=\frac{\frac{|y^2-x^2|+x^2+xy}{\sqrt{y^2-x^2}}}{|y^2-x^2|}\\=\frac{|y^2-x^2|+x^2+xy}{(y^2-x^2)^{3/2}}$$